# Efficiently convert std::vector types

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, std

I have some geometry data given as an array of floats, where three subsequent floats make up a vertex in 3D. In order to more conveniently work data I would like to convert that to a vec3 representation. This allows me to define operators for that struct (or in fact use the ones already defined by some library). Thus i do **not want to copy** or change any of the data itself i only want to change how said data is seen. The way to convert the types that I found however does seem to copy instead of reference the original array as tested below.

```
struct vec3{
    float x,y,z;
};
int main() {
    vector<float> input;
    float* arrayInput = &input[0];
    vec3* arrayOut = reinterpret_cast<vec3*>(arrayInput);
    vector<vec3> output = vector<vec3>(arrayOut,arrayOut+input.size()/3);
}
```

If we make a simple test case we can see that the data in range-constructor actually does copy the values.

```
float some[]{1,2,3,4};
vector<float> vector(some,some+4);
some[3]=5;
std::cout << vector[3] << std::endl;
```

(Returns 4 instead of 5 as i would like it to.)

As i literally never touch the input array again is there a way to avoid copying and yet keep the convince of the vector representation?

Comment: A `std::vector` owns it's elements. There is no portable way of doing this with `std::vector`. Additionally, aliasing rules forbids the conversion from `float*` to `vec*`. Have you tried just doing the copy and measured it to be problematic?

Comment: I just do some prototype implementations and thought wow copying all this stuff seems inefficient.

Comment: If you know that vertices will always consists of 3 floats, why don't you use a vector<vec3>? If you really can not, you can also use a structure holding iterators, but those might be invalidated at any moment.

Comment: I use tinyobj loader to read in the values, which returns basically a vector<float> and I don't want to edit library itself. Though in this case that may actually be a feasible option.

Comment: @Knork C++ is getting better at avoiding unnecessary copies, but it still isn't perfect. For example, with the introduction of move semantics and guaranteed copy elision, most of the common cases of unnecessary copying are in the past. However, aliasing rules and object life-time requirements still sometimes impose some annoying copies. The problem is getting ride of those restrictions would disable many powerful optimizations and, in the end, it would be a net loss in performance in most cases.

Comment: must it be `struct vec3{ float x,y,z; };`? can you instead use something akin to `struct vec3{ float & x; float & y; float & z; };`?

Comment: The intermediate step of casting from float* to vec3* is already undefined behavior. The compiler is free to lay out a plain struct the way it wants, as long as the order is preserved (even this guarantee won't hold if you add access specifiers. It can insert padding if it sees it fit.